# RequiredFieldValidator on drop down list not accepting IntialValue for null object

Tags: c#, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I have read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638768/required-field-validator-disappears-on-dropdownlist-post-back) which helped me narrow down my validation problems to the `InitialValue` property of the `RequiredFieldValidator`.

My drop down list is a list of objects which are populated by the code behind like this;

```
brands.Insert(0, Brand.Empty)

cbBrand.DataValueField = "ID";
cbBrand.DataTextField = "Name";
cbBrand.DataSource = new BindingList<Brand>(brands);
cbBrand.DataBind();
```

where Brand.Empty is a null object type.

Where I'm coming unstuck is getting the `IntialValue` to accept a null value. For instance, `InitialValue=""` fails to recognise the empty object in the list.

Can anyone point me in the direction of a fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow. I thought I had searched previous answers on this site very thoroughly before posting this question, but I had missed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521334/databound-drop-down-list-initial-value)!!

The answer is to change your `<asp:DropDownList>` to have the property `AppendDataBoundItems=true`, Then add an `<asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" />` between the dropDownList tags and BAM! you can insert a value to the list that does not require the null object inserted in the code behind (which should be removed so that you don't end up with 2 blanks at the start of your list).

The benefit here is that the list in my code-behind is bound to an object type `<Brand>`, but adding the empty string at the client works fine for client-side validation.

Hope this helps anyone else struggling with this problem!

Answer (score 1):

An empty string is not the same as a null value.  Instead of adding a null value to your data source, add it to the drop down directly like :

```
cbBrand.Insert(0, new ListItem("", "Select an item"));
```

That will add a option to your HTML select element with a value of "", which matches the validators initial value.

Comment: Thanks Ken, appreciate the answer. The problem with inserting a custom string while the list is loaded is that the list `cbBrand` is expecting a type `<Brand>`. I found a way around this problem (embarrasingly from another post on SO :S) and will post it below. Thanks again!